# Rails 4 cache: How to disable default caching for particular controller action or view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, caching, fragment-caching

We have `Rails 4.2` application running on production with the following configurations (cache related). And we have not implemented any caching technique so far (default setup).

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

# Use a different cache store in production.
# config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store
```

I am having an issue with particular view which is not showing updated data accordingly.

Is there a way that I can disable fragment caching for particular view not in entire application?

Comment: Why not just remove your `cache some_model do` block from that view?

Comment: @omnikron - no such code written in the view. Its I think Rails handles internally

Comment: No, you have to call `cache` explicitly, or your view will simply not be cached. If you don't have that anywhere, then none of your views are being cached, unless you are doing something else.  See the [rails caching documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching) for more info. Maybe you were confused by where it says "By default Rails provides fragment caching"? This just means that it is available by default – it doesn't actually implement it for you.

Comment: @omnikron - Not really sure. But it worth to cross check. Thanks

Comment: @omnikron - You're right! I am really confused with the similar views in the application. Thanks for your comment for my dumb statements above :)

Comment: Haha, no worries! Glad to be able to help :)

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: while caching can cause problems, it's worth verifying that you are actually using it before trying to fix it!

The simplest way to disable caching for a single view is also the most obvious (but potentially quite easy to miss):

> Remove the `cache model do` block from inside your view.

Rails does not do any caching for you by default, so this will take care of it entirely. If you don't have a call to `cache` with a block inside your view, you are *not using caching*.

E.g:

Cached:

```
# app/views/something_important/show.html.haml
= cache something_important do
  = render_something_expensive
```

Not cached:

```
# app/views/something_important/show.html.haml
= render_something_expensive
```